# How to get more information from Server about why page is loading so slow initially?

Tags: iis-7.5, umbraco, asp.net-4.0, performance-testing, glimpse

I am using Glimpse and have attached a screenshot of what it tells me on a specific initial page load (after which is cached and loads fine), but when I touch the web.config, this flushes out the cache ofcourse, and the initial page load is what the pic says it is.  The most time spent is on the server, but is there a plugin for Glimpse or something else that I can use to find out exactly where the problem is located on the server??

[image: Glimpse Results for a specific page]

The problem is specifically with this one template, but I can not determine what is taking it soooo long to load initially.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  The template runs several User Controls, so it would be a lot of code to post up and ties into a Document Type in the back end of Umbraco 4.6.1 CMS.  All other Document types seem to work fine, except for this specific one.

Answer (score 1):

In 4.6.1 you should ensure that you have set the value for `umbracoDebugMode` in the appSettings section of your web.config to `true`. Once you have done that you can append `?umbDebugShowTrace=true` to the url to see a breakdown of the elements on the page and how long they took to load via the trace that gets displayed.

See http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos for reference

Comment: There is a custom handler handling all urls on the website.  I don't know how to disable it without messing up the entire site!  Unfortunately, this handler that rewrites urls, also does not allow Umbraco to show a trace on anything other than the homepage!

Comment: You really shouldn't as it misleads others. You need to provide more information about the handler so you can disable it and enable the trace. You never know the handler could be the source of your trouble.

Comment: I found the problem, just not sure how to fix it.  Able to get trace information here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921341/umbraco-reserved-paths-urls-is-taking-37-seconds-to-load-a-page-why

Comment: Your other post seems to have been removed so guessing you have resolved the issue?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the problem.  Thanks.  It was in my code, it was trying to call a method that didn't exist on a Node, and was taking a long time to respond.  Glimpse actually provides a tab for a trace on any page and wasn't aware of that, as umbDebugShowTrace=true did not help on the actual page output!  Thanks much anyways!